# Bootstrap4 navbar toggle not working correctly

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have some problem about toggling navbar button. It is not toggling correctly. When i hit the button, toggle background showing and dissappearing immediately. Here is my code and Fiddle file:

https://jsfiddle.net/85uyhbv6/

```
<!-- Navigation -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark sticky-top bg-custom">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent"
            aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse text-center" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul class="navbar-nav navbar-center">
                <li class="nav-item active">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#top-img">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#games-tag">Games</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#team-tag">Team</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">About Us</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

```
.bg-gray{
    background-color: #b8b8b8;
}

.bg-custom{
    background-color: #170c37;
}

.navbar-brand{
    font-family: roboto-thin;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 28px;
}

.navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link{
    font-family: roboto-thin;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 16px;
}

.navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-item{
    margin: 0 15px;
}

.navbar-center{
    position: absolute; 
    left: 50%; 
    transform: translatex(-50%)
}
```

I think position absolute is causing the problem but i cant center the items correctly without it.
Thanks for helping.

Comment: if you remove your css from **.navbar-center** then it will work as expected & it will not add any impact on the alignment of the menu items, by default they are aligned center.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you remove your css from `.navbar-center` then it will work as expected & it will not add any impact on the alignment of the menu items, by default they are aligned center.

**or**

Just add `min-height: 160px;` on class `.collapse.show` and it will work.

Here is the working example:

```css
.collapse.show {
    min-height: 160px;
}

.bg-gray{
    background-color: #b8b8b8;
}

.bg-custom{
    background-color: #170c37;
}

.navbar-brand{
    font-family: roboto-thin;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 28px;
}

.navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link{
    font-family: roboto-thin;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 16px;
}

.navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-item{
    margin: 0 15px;
}

.navbar-center{
    position: absolute; 
    left: 50%; 
    transform: translatex(-50%)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<!-- Navigation -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark sticky-top bg-custom">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent"
            aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse text-center" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul class="navbar-nav navbar-center">
                <li class="nav-item active">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#top-img">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#games-tag">Games</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#team-tag">Team</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">About Us</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1):

remove `position: absolute;` in `.navbar-center` class and insert `position: relative;`

```css
.bg-gray{
    background-color: #b8b8b8;
}

.bg-custom{
    background-color: #170c37;
}

.navbar-brand{
    font-family: roboto-thin;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 28px;
}

.navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link{
    font-family: roboto-thin;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 16px;
}

.navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-item{
    margin: 0 15px;
}

.navbar-center{
    /*position: absolute;*/
    position: relative;
    left: 50%; 
    transform: translatex(-50%)
}
```

```html
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link href="../static/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

    <!-- Navigation -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark sticky-top bg-custom">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent"
                aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>

            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse text-center" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                <ul class="navbar-nav navbar-center">
                    <li class="nav-item active">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#top-img">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#games-tag">Games</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#team-tag">Team</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">About Us</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
  
  </body>
```

Comment: Yeah i tried this before but it is not align items on the center. If you write something like <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">BrandBrandBrandBrandBrand</a> you will see the problem but thanks anyway.